# If the domain of a function is $[0,2]$, what is the domain of $f(2x+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the domain of a function is $[0,2]$, what is the domain of $f(2x+1)$?

**Attempt**

if $0\leq x\leq2$ then $1\leq 2x+1\leq 5$, so the domain is $[1,2]$??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guide:

You want to have $$0 \le 2x+1 \le 2$$

so that when $f$ evaluates $2x+1$, it is well define. Hence, just you just have to solve the inequality above.

Comment: got it!! Thanks